# Touch ID setup fails on new (duplicate) user account

Tags: macbook-pro, authentication, touch-id, setup

I duplicated my account based on [this answer.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/39488/8620) After the procedure, macOS asked me to set up Touch ID.

I tried multiple times with many different fingers, but I couldn't get it to fully scan the fingerprint. The last "lines" would never fill up, and I couldn't get to the part where you're asked to scan the sides of your finger.

This process still works fine on the original account. No finger scans correctly on the duplicate account.

How can I make Touch ID work correctly on my duplicate account?

Comment: It seems like this issue only affects my duplicate account. Freshly created accounts are not affected. I tried many things to no avail, including resetting SMC and NVRAM, rebooting many times, changing the username and full name of my user, inspecting the console for errors when setting up Touch ID.

Comment: I ended up having to create a new account manually and configuring it from scratch, unfortunately. Fingerprint recognition works very well with this account, even on the same finger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine (but have not verified) this is because the fingerprints are the same – macOS is identifying that you are the same person. If it allowed registering the same fingerprint twice, it wouldn't know which account to unlock when you touched the sensor.

Comment: Thanks, but I doubt that's the case; in the end I made a new account manually, and my fingerprint (same finger) is accepted and it even works well for switching between my two accounts.